# Re-using computations in several least squares problems

Tags: linear-model, linear-algebra

I have $K$ least squares problems of the form $Y_k = X_k\beta_k$ for $k = 1, \dots, n$. If the matrix $X_k$ is the same for each index $k$, we can rewrite the problem as $Y_k = X \beta_k$. How can I speed up least squares by knowing this additional information? The values of $Y_k$ change.

Of course if $K=1$, it's just a a single linear regression problem. But how can I reuse my work? Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Reusing your work is a good idea. To start, let's review how the `lm` function in `R` calculates least squares estimates. We'll assume throughout that $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ has full rank and that $n \geq p$.

The function calculates that $X=QR$, where $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ has orthonormal columns and $R \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ is upper triangular. Then, it uses this decomposition to quickly calculate $$(X^TX)^{-1}X^T Y_k = R^{-1} Q^T Y_k$$ by taking the matrix-vector product $Q^T Y_k$ and then backsolving. Notice that the decomposition of $X$ does not rely on the response $Y_k$. This suggests a general strategy: we can calculate a something involving $X$ once and then reuse it for each response vector.

If you have a very large number of response vectors, it will be advantageous to actually compute $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$. Then each calculation of a least squares coefficient will only involve a matrix-vector product and avoid backsolving.

Otherwise, simply storing the $QR$ decomposition of $X$ will greatly speed up your least squares run time.

Comment: This is a great answer--I wonder why you deleted it?  Am I overlooking some subtlety or limitation?

Comment: Thanks @whuber . I wanted to add some flop counts and fix the error saying the R uses LU.